# how do I get the minimum to print properly?

Tags: c

This is supposed to ask the user to input a number than if the number is positive it outputs the number and adds one to the `count` and outputs the value of `count` (just for the most recent input value). if the number `input` is negative it just asks for a new number and if the input is 0 it outputs the count, minimum, maximum, sum and average for the entire run of the program.

I've gotten most of it working I'm just having trouble with getting the minimum value for the 0 scenario. I also get a runtime error for `int min`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int input = 7;
    int count = 0;
    int sumInput = 0;
    int lastInupt = 0;
    int max;
    int min;
    double avg;

    while (input != 0) {
        printf("enter a number\n");
        scanf("%i", &input);
        if (input > 0) {
            count++;
            printf("\ninput = %i", input);
            printf("\ncount = %i\n", count);
            /*input1 = input;*/
            sumInput += input;
            //lastInupt = input;
        }
        else if (input < 0) {
            printf("\ninput = %i", input);
            printf("\ncount = %i\n", count);
        }
        if (input > lastInupt) {
            if (input > max) {
                max = input;
                /*input1 = input;*/
            }
        }
        if (lastInupt > input) {
            if (min > input){
                min = input;
            }
        }
        /*while (min > 0)
        {
        if (input < min) {
        min = input1;
        }
        }*/
    }
    avg = (float)sumInput / (float)count;
    printf("you have entered %i positive numbers..\n", count);
    printf("Sum of inputs: %i", sumInput);
    printf("\nThe maximum # is: %i", max);
    printf("\nThe average is: %.2lf", avg);
    printf("\nThe minimum # is: %i", min);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The code has to keep the same general format this is an assignment for my college.

Comment: just add one more "else" after the "if input < 0" case. this will be the input == 0 case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider initializing both min and max and skip the lastInput variable.

```
int min = INT_MAX;
int max = INT_MIN;

.....

if (input > max) 
   max = input;

if (min > input)
    min = input;
```

This should ensure that min and max are always initialized, and in the special case where the first and only input is 0 both min and max will get the value 0.

Because you initialize `min` to `MAX_INT` (the highest possible value for an int variable) the first iteration `min > input` will always evaluate to true and `min` will be updated. Similar for `max` and `MIN_INT`

if min and max only should be updated when input !=0 then modify the entire program to

```
int main() {
    int input = 7;
    int count = 0;
    int sumInput = 0;
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int min = INT_MAX;
    double avg;

    while (input != 0) {
        printf("enter a number\n");
        scanf("%i", &input);
        if (input > 0) {
            count++;
            printf("\ninput = %i", input);
            printf("\ncount = %i\n", count);

            sumInput += input;
            if (input > max ) max = input;
            if (input < min ) min = input;
        }
        else if (input < 0) {
            printf("\ninput = %i", input);
            printf("\ncount = %i\n", count);
        }       
    }
    if(count==0) { // only 0 entered.
       printf("inform user she didnt enter any positive numbers");
    } else   {
      avg = (float)sumInput / (float)count;
      printf("you have entered %i positive numbers..\n", count);
      printf("Sum of inputs: %i", sumInput);
      printf("\nThe maximum # is: %i", max);
      printf("\nThe average is: %.2lf", avg);
      printf("\nThe minimum # is: %i", min);
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That fixed the runtime error but minimum still comes up as 0

Comment: Did you drop the lastInput variable ? And are you supposed to update the min and max value if input is 0 ?

Comment: Yes to both questions? What should happen if the user enters 0 , should min and max be updated or not? if not then move the `(input > max)`  and `(min > input)` inside the `if (input > 0)` block. And then you need to consider what to use in your printf statements to avoid printing INT_MAX and INT_MIN

Answer (score 0):

Since your runtime error was fixed, I will address the min == 0 issue.

When a 0 is input, it will fail the two first if statements `input>0` and `input < 0`

But it still will try the last two if statements, and of course 0 will be less than the current min, so it will set min to 0 (incorrectly)

What you need to do is put this after the `else if(input < 0)` block

```
else{//input is 0
   break;
}
```

So that it will skip checking if input is below min when input is 0. As you want to break from the loop at this point anyway.

Comment: The issue I'm having is the minimum not calculating, Everything else is working properly. other than I runtime error after the first input. try running the code.